# Nuxt 404 Page on Refresh of page

Tags: nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt. I have made one static site that turned out great but now making a site with dynamic content (like a blog). I would have a structure like so:

```
->posts/
-->index.vue
-->_slug.vue
```

When running `npm run dev` I can go to `mysite.test/posts/slug-1` and I get the page I want. If I refresh I still get that page I want.

The issue comes when I build it. I use `npm run build --spa` (not generate, I know generate creates static files and I would have to make a static file for each post). Now if I go to `mysite.test/posts/` and click on a post, it navigates to `mysite.test/posts/slug-1` and it works. If I go to the URL directly or refresh, it does not?

The site clearly says SPA mode works with dynamic routes, but it from what I see it only works to navigate to them, not direct link?

Comment: yes, you need to setup a proxy that will proxy request to index.html.

Comment: @Aldarund is there any docs on this? Seems like something that should be mentioned when using the SPA function

Comment: it is how any spa app works in the world. You can google it via spa nginx configaration for exmaple and its totally depends on how u host your app

Answer (score -2):

Nuxt does not know what dynamic routes you have, and therefore you need to specify them in the generate configuration option in `nuxt.config.js`. Read more [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes).

You would do something like this:

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    routes: [
      '/posts/slug-1',
      '/posts/slug-2',
      '/posts/slug-3'
    ]
  }
}
```

After doing this, it will no longer give you a 404 on the dynamically routed pages if you refresh.

Comment: note that you can actually make an ```async routes()``` and generate the pages dynamically